# update_post_meta to add featured image to post no longer works after update to wordpress 3.5.1

Tags: thumbnails, wordpress-3.5

I have written a plugin which uses :

add_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );

To set the featured image for a post. This plugin has been working nicely for over a year. I updated to wordpress 3.5.1 and it no longer works. No featured image is set.

I have tried using add_post_meta and set_post thumbnail, but to no avail. Has any one else had this problem and most importantly, does any one know what to do to solveit?

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for a solution to set the featured image on a post, I am using

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
```

and it works just fine for me hope you get similar luck.

Thanks

Comment: if the value doesn't exist this defaults to add_post_meta instead, which is good!

Comment: I received error: Undefined variable `$attach_id`. How to fix it?

Comment: what is $attach_id mean here? is it the url of the image?